# What are the average transport fees for travel in Denpasar?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia

What are the usual expected fees for transportation fares in Denpasar?

For instance, if I have a journey of 10km, what would I approximately pay to do this journey by:

1. Public bus (Bemo)
2. Motorcycle taxi (Ojek)
3. Taxi

Finally, if there is a fare difference between day and night time, can you tell us how this is estimable?

Comment: This can not be answered, for taxis it depends on the traffic as well (waiting time) and for the bemos it depends on the route (how many rides you need to reach there), for ojek it is by agreement, 10 km is quite far by ojek.

Comment: Assuming you only need one bemo ride, would it then be possible to estimate this?

Comment: bemo for 10 km? not sure of that.. they usually operate in short routes.. are you talking about rekshas-like things? or little minivans?

Comment: Little minivans. Thought they would, i.e. To go from Denpasar to Kuta

Comment: you said "in Denpasar"... hence my assumption was about rides in town.. and my experience mainly about Jakarta..

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for that. It's just so close that it does feel like it's part of Denpasar.

Comment: @AdrienBe did you travel to Denpasar? Could you post some approximate fare estimates?

Comment: Bali is really terrible for transportation. Taxi gangs are everywhere. If you want great prices, safety & great service, then use Uber when in Bali. 10km probably will cost you around 75'000 IDR, my estimation may be a little bit incorrect (i left a few months ago now) but you can expect to pay around 2 times more whatever fare Uber quotes you if you take "just any taxi I the street".

Comment: @AdrienBe can you post this comment as an answer? :)

Comment: @JonathanReez done. And with a few more info ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Bali & its old-fashioned transports

Bali is really terrible for transportation. Everything is pretty great in Bali, except transportation. Public transportation is almost non-existing & taxis often (always?) try to trick tourists.

Taxi gangs are everywhere in Bali. They even have "territories" in some areas. Which means only taxis from the "taxi gang" can pick up passengers in a given area.

---

### Uber in Bali

If you want **great prices**, **safety** & **great service**, then use **Uber** (or another Taxi app) when in Bali.

As an example, going from Bali airport to Canggu, around **20km** with Uber will cost you between **65'000 & 82'000 IDR**. But you can expect to pay around 2 times more if you take "just about any other taxi".

---

### Other taxi app

**Grab (GrabTaxi)** on [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/grabtaxi-book-a-ride/id647268330?mt=8) & [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grabtaxi.passenger&hl=en) is also a taxi app worth using in Bali or anywhere else in Southeast Asia. I actually used it a couple of times & it was decent.

**Go-Jeck** on [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go-jek/id944875099?mt=8) & [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gojek.app) is a different one: it is a **motorcycle-taxi app**! Incredibly useful if you are in a place with a lot of traffic. I have not tried it myself but several friends have & said it was great. I expect prices to be even cheaper than Uber or GrabTaxi.

**What's special about Go-Jeck**: you can also use it for **shopping** (yes, the rider will shop for you at the store you indicate) or to **deliver things** (from you to someone else, or vice-versa). A friend did use it to order a Nasi-Goreng across town at 2am... and it worked. Your creativity is the limit.

---

#### Related

https://www.techinasia.com/10-taxi-booking-apps-asia

https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-thoughts-about-GO-JEK